# How to access shared drive from internet - openmediavault

Tags: raspberry-pi, nas, openmediavault, shared-drive

I am using OpenMediaVault for NAS management installed on Raspberry Pi. I am able to access my shared drive on my network. I would like to access it from the internet. I have static IP connection and have done the port forwarding. I am able to access the OpenMediaVault configuration page from other network, but cannot access the shared drive.

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there should be multiple ways to do this.  But following is how I access my NAS on Raspi from the internet.

1. Registered a free domain on DuckDNS for Private VPN
2. Used the domain created in #1 to set up a split tunnel Wireguard VPN server using PiVPN on the RaspberryPi
3. Set up a split-tunnel VPN profile
4. Forwarded port 51820 (default port for Wireguard) on the router
5. Installed Wireguard on my phone and Mac and set the connections

Whenever I'm outside the home network, I just connect to the VPN and I can access my shared folders.